# Grails, jquery-date-time-picker not working properly

Tags: jquery, grails, datepicker

I tried to use the jquery-date-time-picker: `https://github.com/zoran119/grails-jquery-date-time-picker`

I added the following lines to my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"
compile ":jquery-date-time-picker:0.2.0"
```

Now I tried in my template (`_form.gsp`, generated from grails) following command like described in the documentation:

```
<jqueryPicker:time name="end" value="${DailyBookingInstance?.end}"/>
```

This does actually nothing, it just appears a normal text field for input.

Comment: I dont have that plugin, but just try it like this `<g:textField name="dateField" class="datePicker" />`

Comment: I dont want the normal datePicker because I want to select just the time (hours, minutes)

Comment: Try jodaTime instead <joda:timePicker name="setTime" value="" /> https://github.com/vahidhedayati/mailinglist/blob/master/grails-app/views/mailingListEmail/contactclients.gsp#L202

Comment: Yeah, seems like the best idea. Unfortunately I cant use LocalTime since import org.joda.time.LocalTime can not be resolved